# how to consume events from kafka by a Spring Rest endpoint

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm new to Kafka. I've seen that the consumer is "always running" and retrieves messages from a topic as soon as been published.

In a typical database web application you have a rest API that connects to DB and returns some response.

From what I see the consumer stays active and never close.
So I don't figure out how to return a subset of messages from a topic based on client request.

I thought the service would create a consumer to get what I need, but as far as consumer never close, I guess my opinion is not correct.
What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean that `org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @k-wasilewski I guess KafkaListener remains to wait to receive new messages from a topic.
I want my client calls an API with a start time and an end time interval. The service should take all the messages for that interval.

Answer (score 0):

Then it's a simple question of persisting messages rceived thru KafkaListener, let's say adding each of them to a simple collecton (along with its timestamp) and implementing an endpoint to filter the messages accordingly and returning some of them.

```
@Controller
public class KafkaController {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducerConfig kafkaProducerConfig;
    private Map<Date, String> msgMap = new HashMap();

    @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId = "myGroup")
    public void listenAndAddMsg(String message) {
        msgMap.put(new Date(), message);
    }

    @PostMapping("messages")
    @ResponseBody
    public String filterMessages(@RequestBody Interval interval) {
        return msgMap.entrySet() 
          .stream() 
          .filter(map -> map.getKey().after(interval.getStartDate()) && map.getKey().before(interval.getEndDate()))
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(map -> map.getKey(), map -> map.getValue()));  
    }
}

public class Interval {
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    // setters and getters
}
```

Comment: In your example, I guess you are adding every message to a map and you simply filter by that map. That means storing everything in memory. I could save it directly to memory instead of using Kafka but I should have 1.500.000 objects per day and store up to 3 months...
I'd like to tell the consumer: give me all the messages from this date to this date (usually not more than 3 days). is it possible?

Comment: No, that's your concern as a backend developer. So, instead of storing messages in a map, store them in database...